# Regular Expression not recongnizing letters C,F etc

Tags: c#, regex

How do I get the 'F'?

Pattern: `(\d+),(\d+),0,(\d+),0,(\d+)[<CR><LF>\\r\\n ]+(\w+)`
String: `13,33333,0,55555,0,16\\r\\nFE01`

[image]

Comment: You are not matching CR and LF symbols correctly, just use `@"(\d+),(\d+),0,(\d+),0,(\d+)\s+(\w+)"` - if the `\\r\\n`  is in fact a line break. If it is not, use `@"(\d+),(\d+),0,(\d+),0,(\d+)\s*\\r\\n\s*(\w+)"`

Comment: Are you using single line or multi-line mode?  The returns have different meaning depending on the mode.

Comment: @jdweng In this case, `RegexOptions.Singleline` and `RegexOptions.Multiline` won't affect matching (no `.`, `^` and `$` are in the pattern).

Comment: The \w+ is on a separate line so the mode will affect results.

Comment: @jdweng The options you meant only affect how some specific patterns match a string. Here, `[<CR><LF>\\r\\n ]+`  does not match line breaks, only ``\``, `r`, `n`, `<`, `C`, `R`, `L`, `F`.....chars, that is why it it grabs ``\\r\\nF`` chunk. If those options are used or not used, there will be no difference in output with the current pattern.

Comment: The current pattern is mot working and needs to be changed.  I'm just trying to explain why it is not working.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Yes true. Removing the <CR><LF> worked. Thank you.

Comment: So, what worked for you?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew (\d+),(\d+),0,(\d+),0,(\d+)[\\r\\n ]+(\w+).

Comment: @MaheshaKumar But that is the same as `@"(\d+),(\d+),0,(\d+),0,(\d+)[\\rn ]+(\w+)"`. You need `@"(\d+),(\d+),0,(\d+),0,(\d+)(?:\\[rn]|\s)+(\w+)"` I believe

Answer (score 0):

You may use

```
@"(\d+),(\d+),0,(\d+),0,(\d+)(?:\\[rn]|\s)+(\w+)"
```

It will match

- `(\d+)` - Group 1: one or more digits
- `,` - a comma
- `(\d+)` - Group 2: one or more digits
- `,0,` - a `,0,` substring
- `(\d+)` - Group 3: one or more digits
- `,0,` - a `,0,` substring
- `(\d+)` - Group 4: one or more digits
- `(?:\\[rn]|\s)+`  - 1 or more occurrences of `\r`, `\n`, or whitespace
- `(\w+)` - Group 5: one or more word chars.